# Why is the output in my cell being truncated even though textOutputLimit is set to 0? (Jupyter Notebook, VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, data-science, jupyter

The result in one of my cells is truncated with the message: "Output was trimmed for performance reasons.
To see the full output set the setting "python.dataScience.textOutputLimit" to 0."

From researching answers to similar questions, I modified the settings.json to include the following line of code: 
`"python.dataScience.textOutputLimit": 0`. However, the same message keeps showing up in the output.

What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. That setting should be the correct one. I just tested it myself and it did correctly stop truncating after I changed it to zero. A couple of things to try.

1. Did you re-execute that cell after changing the setting? It doesn't apply to an already executed cell, just one that is executed after the setting change.
2. VSCode can apply settings either at the User or Workspace level. Could you possibly have that setting not applying to your current file? If you open the command > Preferences: Open Settings (UI) from the VSCode command palette you can search for textOutputLimit to check that it's set to 0 in the current context that you are working in. In that screen you can see both User (all workspaces) and Workspace (current workspace only) contexts for that setting.

Does that help to resolve it?

Comment: I am using this with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20) and the latest insider edition of VSCode installed today (07/29/2021) and this setting is not working although I have this set to 0 for all three contexts (User, Remote WSL and Workspace)

Comment: Actually the output is there but VS Code does not show it (shows a 'show more...' message) if you save the notebook and you open it via the browser you will see the entire output

Answer (score 1):

We need to ensure following  two conditions so the notebook output does not give 'show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ...' message.

1. set textOutputLimit to 0 in both user and workspace
2. In setting, search 'output', then look for features>Notebook>Output:Text Line Limit. set the limit to your choice, e.g. 2000

The above settings work for me in the following version/platform:
Version: 1.59.1 (system setup)
Commit: 3866c3553be8b268c8a7f8c0482c0c0177aa8bfa
Date: 2021-08-19T11:56:46.957Z
Electron: 13.1.7
Chrome: 91.0.4472.124
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.36-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Comment: This works! I didn't even know `notebook` settings existed. I was looking for `jupyter` options. So in vscode the jupyter extension is built on top of a common notebook?